# Magento 2 - Page Builder Media Gallery not loading - "You entered an invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page."

Tags: magento2, session, magento2-enterprise, magento-2-commerce, page-builder

If I add a **media** node to the page builder and try to select an image from the gallery, then nothing happens. Normally the gallery should load.

[image]

I get this in the network console

```
https://company.de/backendlogin/cms/wysiwyg_images/index/key/095a7a5f8e56bbf90e8337f93695509fa2e57b0863e15518e17b60f110f3779b/target_element_id/BCP3YMC/store/1/type/image/?isAjax=true&current_tree_path=d3lzaXd5Zw--
    
{"error":true,"message":"You entered an invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page."}
```

[image]

I flushed the cache and deleted all browser cookies, but it does not help.

The project is in production mode.

Comment: Could you fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: @MarceloRodovalho, Yes, I added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a patch that should resolve the reported issue available in the Magento Quality Patches package (MQP).

#### Patch Summary:

Page builder config is now cached per user session if secret key is enabled in backend URLs. (for v2.4.2)

To apply the patch using MQP, please follow the steps below:

1. Install the MQP package: `./composer require magento/quality-patches`
2. Apply the patch: `./vendor/bin/magento-patches apply MDVA-32133`
3. Clean the cache: `./bin/magento cache:clean`

Additional documentation on how to use the MQP tool.

https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-patch.html

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

May be your secret key got expired, please use `postman` to test if your API and secret key is working properly there and you are getting proper JSON response.

Comment: I am not using an API. This is standard magento 2. I also deleted cookies as mentioned, so the session is fresh.

Comment: May you try to delete session also

Comment: It may be helpful - https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/media-gallery.html

Comment: How is a user guide going to help me with the bug?